# Kafka use case: continuously read from kafka, perform decryption on message, then insert to db

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, apache-kafka-connect

Kafka use case: continuously read from Kafka (perhaps a stream), perform decryption on message value with Java method, then insert to db (either sink connector or I have a Java REST API that can insert to db if it's needed)

I haven't seen any viable solutions to this use case BECAUSE:

1. I can't store decrypted data in kafka.
2. I need to perform decryption step before inserting to db.

Looking at Kafka Connect and Kafka Streams to solve the use case:

It doesn't seem like I can use Kafka Connect because I don't see how I could include the decryption step.

It doesn't seem like I can use Kafka Streams because 1. It's built for reading and writing back to topics. 2. Even if I used the Processor API to implement custom logic, I don't see how I can convert the `KStream` message value to a `String` that I can pass to my Java decryption method or database.

I have a solution working that uses the regular Kafka Consumer in a Java app but it does it as a 1 off batch job, I need an application that is long living and continuously checks the Kafka queue.  I could infinitely loop through the batch job but I'm not sure that's a viable option.

How could I accomplish this use case? Spark isn't an option for us.

Comment: so, you can do transformation and insertion, but cannot do decryption before that? Why can't you just call to some decrypt() method, though you can call to transform() and insert()? What is the difference?

Comment: I'm not doing a call to a transform or insert method, Kafka Connect can be configured with smt's that perform transformations and it has a connector to a database sink

Comment: Why don't you use a stored procedure (DB level) on inserts in order to decrypt your inserted records?

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous that's an interesting solution however the db we are using doesnt support stored procedures

Comment: @Artanis What database are you using?

Comment: this is using cosmos cassandra api

Comment: why don't you just add decryptor in the transformation chain of the Kafka Connect configuration?

Comment: @Alexei Kaigorodov is there anything that leads you to believe I'm able to pass the kafka message to my decryptor by using the kafka connect configuration

Comment: @Artanis my understanding is decryption is just another transformation and as such can be added to the transformation chain of the Kafka Connect configuration. You already have one transformation there, so adding another transformation should be trivial. Or may be you have no access to the Kafka Connect configuration?

Comment: the transforms with kafka connect are done by smt's which are statements in the config file, the decryption im using needs to pass the message to my java decryption method

Answer (score 0):

You should use Kafka Connect and write a custom SMT by implementing `Transformation` interface:

https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/transforms/Transformation.java

Check out this talk for more details: https://www.confluent.io/thank-you/single-message-transformations-not-transformations-youre-looking/